# Microsoft team - How to maintain user data

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am integrating my SAAS application to Microsoft Teams. Right now integrated as Tab in teams. I am using my own API endpoint to authenticate and authorize the user. I have got some specific information about the user I am getting from API. How can I store it in Team context? Right now I used local storage in the web app. In Teams web app it seems working but I don't think it is working in Desktop app. Is there some API available in teams which helps to maintain the user state with Tabs? similar to userstate in Bots? Please help.

Comment: Was my answer below of some use?

Comment: I am not saying no. But there is no server side SDK available for teams tab. Only option is use client side code. I raised an issue in Github waiting for the response from Microsoft

Comment: You don't need a server side SDK for this - just do whatever server side that you'd like. For instance, you could have an API that retrieves and saves user state, and you call it client side when you get the teams Context. In that case, it's nothing special to Teams, it's just like any normal SPA app.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Let me explain - I am getting an auth token from API, and for all the later requests I need to append this token. I can't store it in server-side. So I need some mechanism in store these values in client-side team's context.

Comment: Please explain me as well im facing same issue if you have rsolved this issue @Anuraj

Comment: I am yet to look into the solution provided by MSFT team - Here is the issue I raised in GitHub https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/1499

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is a problem for several reasons in Teams, not least of which because it will change from device to device (e.g. desktop to mobile) and modality to modality (e.g. desktop client to web), so it should definitely be avoided unless there's a specific reason (e.g. working area for a short action).

Instead, store your session/user context server side instead, and rely on the user's unique ID to store + access this. In principle, and perhaps in scenarios that don't require much security, you can rely on the AadObjectId from the Teams JS context - this Id is unique to the user but consistent across all of Microsoft 365 (including across devices etc.). Using this Id in this way is not secure though, so it's better to rely on [Teams Tab SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-overview) to get this info, pass it to the backend, and then decode the JWT token on the server side to properly ensure the User Id, Tenant Id, channel, etc. as needed.

To answer the additional question posted in comments of the original post, if you're using one of the MSAL versions (e.g. MSAL React), you can simply re-request the token from the library every time you call the backend.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. There are several things you _need_ to store client-side (not least, a session ID, so the server knows what data to restore from <wherever>)

Comment: This is an old answer, but it does provide the correct guidance. You can see an updated version over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74388424/are-there-any-ways-we-can-store-the-storage-or-local-storage-data-within-the-sub/74388764#74388764. In short, you don't "need" to store anything *at all* "client" side. Microsoft provides, through the Teams js context, a unique ID for every single user, that's unique to that user but consistent across all devices (it's the AadObjectId, which means it's the user's unique ID across all M365).

Comment: That ID can be used consistently on the server side to retrieve any user session info, and my point above is that, storing anything client side will be lost as the user moves from one device to another or from one mode to another (e.g. desktop client to web).

Comment: To even further stress this point, if you're relying purely on client-side info to track session for your user, that's also a security concern, as the client-side data can be extremely easily spoofed. The -proper- way to do this would actually be to make use of Teams SSO, to have a secure token on the server side that contains user Id, Tenant Id, etc. More here as a starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-overview

Comment: Answer updated based on this discussion.