# Are there any ways we can store the storage or local storage data within the subdomain of the MS teams app plugin?

Tags: microsoft-teams

How we can ensure that the stored data cannot be shared between the different domains?
I have some data like personal information, and need to store it in the session storage. When I tried with MS teams web app, session storage data is shared between the domains. Is it expected?

From the console screen, set the sessionStorage.setItem('test', 123);
Check the sessionStorage data in the Application tab by inspect element where we can see sessionStorage data with test is available in the teams.microsoft.com as well as with other subdomains. Is there any ways we can restrict the sessionStorage data flow within the subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

It's for exactly these kinds of reasons, plus others (like the user moving between devices) that I'd recommend to NOT store user information in local/session/cookie storage and rather store the state on your side (e.g. in a database or memory cache or something like that).

The one thing that *is* consistent across the user's journey between tabs/devices/etc. is the AadObject Id (their unique Azure Active Directory user guid), so you would use that as the key for reading/writing your state information.